# Java evaluate string as expression or code execution

Tags: java, apache

Say , i have List of Emp object with name, age and salary attribute .

```
List<Emp> empObj = readEmpDetails();
```

Keeping filter condition from DB or read from flat file. But syntax like below format.

```
name contains mike
age gt 100
```

How can i convert list of above condition to java expression . need to perform this condition against empObj which we read from DB source. How can i do this ? Please share your experience.

Comment: What does emp look like?

Comment: Give it a try. Look forward to using conditions to selective add objects to output while iterating the list.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Spring [Spel](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) (`org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Emp> emp = Arrays.asList(new Emp("Ann", 25, 1000L)
            ,new Emp("John", 40, 2000L)
            ,new Emp("Alex", 60, 3000L));
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("age gt 30");


    emp.stream()
            .filter(emp1 -> exp.getValue(emp1, Boolean.class))
            .forEach(emp1 -> System.out.println(emp1.getName() + " " + emp1.getAge()));
}
```

**Output**:

```
John 40
Alex 60
```

**Types of literals and operations are:**

- Literals:

  - Text literals: 'one text', 'Another one!',…
  - Number literals: 0, 34, 3.0, 12.3,…
  - Boolean literals: true, false
  - Null literal: null
  - Literal tokens: one, sometext, main,…
- Text operations:

  - String concatenation: +
  - Literal substitutions: |The name is ${name}|
- Arithmetic operations:

  - Binary operators: +, -, *, /, %
  - Minus sign (unary operator): -
- Boolean operations:

  - Binary operators: and, or
  - Boolean negation (unary operator): !, not
- Comparisons and equality:

  - Comparators: >, <, >=, <= (gt, lt, ge, le)
  - Equality operators: ==, != (eq, ne)
- Conditional operators:

  - If-then: (if) ? (then)
  - If-then-else: (if) ? (then) : (else)
  - Default: (value) ?: (defaultvalue)

Comment: Woh.. thanks a dude.. this what i need.  have any documentation or source to refer more conditions. Also i need to pass "Boolean.class" as parameter.

Comment: I have just added literals and operations. With "Boolean.class" as parameter, could you give an example? By my opinion filter can be applied only for Boolean condition.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your request, I'll make code like the following.

```
public boolean filter(String name, String search, int age) {
    boolean a = name.contains(search/* mike */);
    boolean b = (age >= 100);
    return a & b;
}
```

The following code is second way after I checked you reply.

```
public ArrayList<Emp> filter() {
    ArrayList<Emp> results = new ArrayList<>();

    this.emps.stream()
            .filter(Main::wordFilterFunc)
            .filter(Main::ageFilterFunc)
            .forEach(emp -> results.add(emp));

    return results;
}

private static boolean wordFilterFunc(Emp word){
    // implement what you want
}

private static boolean ageFilterFunc(Emp word){
    // implement what you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response.. All the values are dynamic. Based on dynamic condition , we need to perform. For example , they may add salary lt 5000

Comment: I see, then how about the second way that I updated?